# Does this Mean Value have a Name?

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics

**Question:**
does the following mean value have a name?

$$v^*=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_iv_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i}}, \alpha_i\in\mathbb{R}^+$$

where the $v_i$ are individual speed limits and the $\alpha_i$ are the cumulated lengths along a route, for which the individual speed limits hold.

the mean value $v^*$ reflects the speed that would incur the same energy consumption if the whole route were traveled with that speed.

The mean is almost the euclidean norm and it should have been encountered before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a weighted quadratic mean (= weighted power mean with parameter $p=2$), see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean.